# Elasticsearch: Disabling Field Length norm is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

The use case is as follows:

1. I am trying to disable norms for a particular field in the document while index creation .
2. For this I have added a setting as follows in the mapping itself.

   ```
   "mappings": {
      "incident": {
           "properties": {
               "Filed1": {
                   "type": "string",
                   **"norms": {
                           "enabled": false
                   }**,
                   "index": "analyzed",
                   "term_vector": "yes"
               },
               "Filed2": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "analyzed",
                   "term_vector": "yes"
               }
           }
       },
       "dynamic_templates": [
           {
               "defaultFieldsNotIndexed": {
                   "match": "*",
                   "match_mapping_type": "*",
                   "mapping": {
                       "index": "no"
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. While executing a more_like_this_query with explain being added in the Rest URL. I observed that the fieldnorm was getting calculated and was also included in the relevance score computation of the document. Following is a snippet:

   ```
   'description': 'fieldNorm(doc=274)', 'details': [], 'value': 0.5}]
   ```
4. The above query shows that the fieldnorm is not yet disabled.

Has anyone faced similar issue, or has any solution to th above problem,i.e., Disabling fieldnorm calculation in the relevance score.?

Comment: Did you try `"norms": false` instead of nested object?

Comment: yes. that also didn't work. The query result still had fieldNorm score and it was used in the final score computation as well. Confirmed by taking product of tf,idf and fieldNorm.

Comment: @NikitaRastogi Did you ever find a solution to this?