# elasticsearch "more_like_this query result": More relevant document got lesser relevance score than the lesser relevant document

Tags: elasticsearch

The scenario is as follows:

1. created an index with documents.
2. tried to execute more_like_this query on the index. It tries to search a keyword in a particular field in all the indexed docs.
3. the obtained result contains unexpected result.
4. the keyword has two letters say A and B, ("A B").
5. the first ranked document contains B and has 4 words in total in the field (based on which search is performed).
6. the second ranked document contains B followed by A ("B A") and the length of the field is 15 words long.
7. the above result seems incorrect. **The more relevant document got lesser relevance score than the lesser relevant document. I have a feeling that fieldnorm being enabled might be the reason.**

Disabling fieldnorm is not working, hence can't narrow down as of now. I've created a post for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722416/elasticsearch-disabling-field-length-norm-is-not-working). **Can there be any other possible reasons for this issue?**

Kindly let me know if any more clarification is required on the issue.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: no, it's not clear, also more like this working a bit differently, that you may expect

Comment: can you explain a bit more or redirect to some resource for this "expected behaviour of more_like_this working a bit differently".